# Is it possible to extract function parameters types from object as tuples?

Tags: typescript, mapped-types

For example I have some object with functions

```
{
 fnNumber: (x: number) => x,
 fnString: (x: string) => x
}
```

and I want to create this type

```
{ 
  fnNumber: number,
  fnString: string
}
```

I can do it like this

```
type FnParam<T> = {[key in keyof T ]: T[key]}
type FnObject<T> = {[key in keyof T]: (x: T[key]) => any}

export function create<T>(x: FnObject<T>): FnParam<T> {
 return {} as any
}

const types = create({
 fnNumber: (x: number) => x,
 fnString: (x: string) => x
})
types: : {fnNumber: number, fnString: string}
```

But if functions have more than one parameter

```
{
 fnNumber: (x: number, y: string) => x,
 fnString: (x: string) => x
}
```

I need to create tuples

```
{ 
  fnNumber: [number, string],
  fnString: [string]
}
```

Something like this

```
type FnParam2<T> = {[key in keyof T ]: T[key]}
type FnObject2<T> = {[key in keyof T]: (...x: T[key]) => any}

export function create2<T>(x: FnObject2<T>): FnParam2<T> {
 return {} as any
}
```

But typescript cannot infer tuple from `...x: T[key]`

Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just as a side note, for your single parameter version you don't need `FnParams`, you can just use `T`. This will yield the same result:

```
export function create<T>(x: FnObject<T>): T {
 return {} as any
}

const types = create({
 fnNumber: (x: number) => x,
 fnString: (x: string) => x
})
// types: : {fnNumber: number, fnString: string}
```

For multiple parameters you will need to use [conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html) to extract the parameters (and this is possible only in Typescript 3.0 or above after [Tuples in rest parameters and spread expressions](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/24897) was introduced).

```
type ArgumentTypes<T> = T extends (...a: infer A) => void ? A : never 
type FnParam<T> = { [key in keyof T]: ArgumentTypes<T[key]> }
type FnObject<T> = Record<string, (...a: any[]) => any>

export function create<T extends FnObject<any>>(x: T): FnParam<T> {
    return {} as any
}

const types = create({
    fnNumber: (x: number, y: string) => x,
    fnString: (x: string) => x
})

types.fnNumber // [number, string]
types.fnString // [string]
```